# Dynamic XML template generation using get_template jinja2

Tags: python, xml, jinja2

I am new in Python as well as in XML, I am using the below python code and xml file to replace the value of variables in xml file and generate another output xml file with updated value in parameter `{{param}}`.

**netconf_payload.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
TEMPLATE_ENVIRONMENT = Environment(
    autoescape=False,
    loader=FileSystemLoader(os.path.join(PATH, 'templates')),
    trim_blocks=False)
def render_template(template_filename, context):
    return TEMPLATE_ENVIRONMENT.get_template(template_filename).render(context)
def create_index_html():
    fname = "bridge.xml"
    param = [3, 'ieee', 3]
    context = {
        'param': param
    }
    #
    with open(fname, 'w') as f:
        html = render_template('bridge.xml', context)
        f.write(html)
def main():
    create_index_html()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**templates/bridge.xml**

```xml
<vr>
        <vrId>0</vrId>
        <bridge>
        {% set counter = 0 -%}
        {% for param in param -%}
                <bridgeId>{{ param }}</bridgeId>
                <bridgeType>{{ param }}</bridgeType>
                <bridgeId>{{ param }}</bridgeId>
        {% set counter = counter + 1 -%}
        {% endfor -%}
        </bridge>
</vr>
```

Now execute the command : **python netconf_payload.py**
It will generate a output **bridge.xml** file as below :

```xml
<vr>
        <vrId>0</vrId>
        <bridge>
        <bridgeId>3</bridgeId>
                <bridgeType>3</bridgeType>
                <bridgeId>3</bridgeId>
        <bridgeId>ieee</bridgeId>
                <bridgeType>ieee</bridgeType>
                <bridgeId>ieee</bridgeId>
        <bridgeId>3</bridgeId>
                <bridgeType>3</bridgeType>
                <bridgeId>3</bridgeId>
        </bridge>
</vr>
```

The expected output I want is:

```xml
<vr>
        <vrId>0</vrId>
        <bridge>
                <bridgeId>3</bridgeId>
                <bridgeType>ieee</bridgeType>
                <bridgeId>3</bridgeId>
        </bridge>
</vr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `param` is a list which always has 3 values? I don't think you want to iterate over it in this case, I think instead you need to reference each item in the list explicitly to get the output you want. E.g.

```
<bridge>
     <bridgeId>{{ param[0] }}</bridgeId>
     <bridgeType>{{ param[1] }}</bridgeType>
     <bridgeId>{{ param[2] }}</bridgeId>
</bridge>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looping over `param`, which is a list of 3 elements:

```
param = [3, 'ieee', 3]
```

For each of these values, you create *3 elements*:

```xml
{% for param in param -%}
        <bridgeId>{{ param }}</bridgeId>
        <bridgeType>{{ param }}</bridgeType>
        <bridgeId>{{ param }}</bridgeId>
{% endfor -%}
```

so your output is entirely expected.

Remove the loop entirely and just insert the 3 elements into 3 separate tags:

```xml
<vr>
        <vrId>0</vrId>
        <bridge>
                <bridgeId>{{ param[0] }}</bridgeId>
                <bridgeType>{{ param[1] }}</bridgeType>
                <bridgeId>{{ param[2] }}</bridgeId>
        </bridge>
</vr>
```

You probably want to use a *dictionary* instead however, as that lets you name the 3 elements:

```
param = {'id1': 3, 'type': 'ieee', 'id2': 3}
```

and

```xml
<vr>
        <vrId>0</vrId>
        <bridge>
                <bridgeId>{{ param.id1 }}</bridgeId>
                <bridgeType>{{ param.type }}</bridgeType>
                <bridgeId>{{ param.id2 }}</bridgeId>
        </bridge>
</vr>
```

or if you needed to produce multiple `bridgeId` and *optional and corresponding `bridgeType` tags, perhaps you want a *list of dictionaries*:

```
param = [{'id1': 3, 'type': 'ieee'}, {'id2': 3}]
```

Note that the second dictionary has no `'type'` key here. Rendering then becomes:

```xml
<vr>
    <vrId>0</vrId>
    <bridge>
    {% for entry in param -%}
        <bridgeId>{{ entry.id }}</bridgeId>
        {% if entry.type %}<bridgeType>{{ entry.type }}</bridgeType>{% endif %}
    {% endfor -%}
    </bridge>
</vr>
```

Comment: Yeah Matijn... thanks for the suggestion - using dict will be more helpful and sort for me....

Comment: One more question please : Can I pass all the parameter "param = [3, 'ieee', 3]"  at runtime ?

Comment: @Rajendra: You mean build the `param` list based on other information? Of course, just do so. That's just another programming problem.